# SAS Months between two time attributes

Tags: sas

I have two date variables:
A, its format is 30APR2013
B, its format is 04/2011.

I want to calculate the months between these two times and use: `Month_Diff=INTCK('MONTH',A, B);`

It is wrong and only returns missing values for the difference.

Comment: Just a note that month isn't a standardized measure of time. You're better of calculating number of days and doing some sort of conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that they are both `DATE` types. I assume they are otherwise SAS should throw an error - but verify.

The primary issue is that your arguments are not in order.

The documentation indicates that the start date comes before the end date. In your case it should look like this: `Month_Diff = INTCK('MONTH',B,A);`

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm